# Android - OpenSL ES high microphone gain

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native, voip, opensl

I am having a similar problem described in this link:

[RecorderObject in OpenSL does not implement the interface to set the volume or configure on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996402/recorderobject-in-opensl-does-not-implement-the-interface-to-set-the-volume-or-c/11137537#11137537)

The problem being that I can't set the volume on the recorder because getting the volume interface for the recorder is not supported by OpenSL ES in Android. This is not an issue with most phones but some phones (such as the Samsung Note 2) the audio that gets captured distorts heavily if you speak into the microphone too loudly.

Is there any work around for adjusting the volume of the captured audio in OpenSL ES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am struggling with a similar problem. I think the only way to do this is to increase the `PCM` recording volume by multiplying samples by some multiplier.

You can take a look at this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150923161151/http://www.ypass.net/blog/2010/01/pcm-audio-part-3-basic-audio-effects-volume-control/) for further information.